# Why making many requests on NodeJS is slow?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I set up a local express server with:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/test', (request, response) => {
    response.sendStatus(200);
});
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {});
```

Then I ran a script with:

```
const axios = require('axios');
async function main() {
    console.time('time');
    const requests = Array(5000).fill().map(() => axios.get('http://localhost:3000/test'));
    await Promise.all(requests);
    console.timeEnd('time');
}
main();
```

And my question is why this script takes 3 seconds on my machine?

I'd expect it to take a few milliseconds just like with any other for loop of 5000 iterations.
Because I'm running the server locally and calling it via localhost, I expect no latency, therefore, the waiting time for the promises should be almost 0.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Also, how can I do many requests at the same time faster?

**EDIT**

Looking here https://stressgrid.com/blog/webserver_benchmark/ I'd expect my single process node server to be able to handle at least 20k requests concurrently without any delay.

So I'm guessing there is some configuration missing on my machine. Maybe some flag when starting the node server?

Comment: It's *very* likely that you won't fire off 5000 requests at once. There is probably a poll of connections used. The express server also probably has a limited amount of handles for requests. All in all, I'd say 3 seconds is quite fast for 5000 requests. Why do you need it faster?

Comment: So, 5000 requests in 3 seconds?  That's 0.6ms per request.  What is slow about that?  Remember, nodejs runs your Javascript as single threaded so each request has to run some http server code, then some Express code, then your request handler.  And it's only taking 0.6ms to do that.  There is also a bunch of TCP stack code running at the OS level for every request, but that is probably in a different thread.  And, then who knows what all Axios is doing on the client side - lots more single threaded code to run there - some of which will be in parallel with other requests, but still adds.

Comment: crab, 5000 requests in 3 secs, that's still very fast

Comment: 0.6ms *is* fairly slow for pure overhead in modern systems

Answer (score 3):

3 things:

- That benchmark is not properly setup.
- Express is the slowest of all NodeJS web frameworks.
- Your machine might be misconfigured.

You can find better benchmarks and a comparison of different frameworks here: https://www.fastify.io/benchmarks/

Their github repo explains all the setup they've done, so you can compare your machine against theirs too.

### 1. Benchmarking

To put it plainly, the benchmark you set up is not valid. It doesn't reproduce any real world scenario, *and* is not optimized for the synthetic scenario it creates.

Just to exemplify, since on Node everything is single threaded, you'd have better performance running requests serially so that connections can be reused (would also need to change your request framework to one that can reuse connections). HTTP 1 doesn't reuse connections if you issue requests in parallel, AND your client isn't setup to reuse connections anyways.

Let's take a look at what results look like after fixing that. On my machine, the benchmark you posted doesn't even run--node crashes if you try to open that many connections simultaneously on the same port. This version has about the same theoretical performance as your benchmark, and it runs:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
async function main() {
  console.info(process.hrtime.bigint() / 1000000n + "ms");
  for (let i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/test");
  }

  console.info(process.hrtime.bigint() / 1000000n + "ms");
}
main();
```

That takes around 3 seconds on my machine (about the same time as yours). Now let's reuse connections:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const http = require("http");

async function main() {
  const httpAgent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true });

  console.info(process.hrtime.bigint() / 1000000n + "ms");
  for (let i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/test", { httpAgent });
  }

  console.info(process.hrtime.bigint() / 1000000n + "ms");
}
main();
```

This takes 800ms.

There's a lot of other details like this that your benchmark misses. I can't summarize all of them. You can compare your benchmark to Fastify's (linked above) to see how each difference impacts your measurement.

### 2. Frameworks

Express has its popularity for being simple, but it is *not* a fast framework. Take a look at more modern ones such as Koa or Fastify. Note that your app likely will do much more than just serve an empty page, so performance of your web framework is likely not important. That said, I don't think anyone should be using express in 2021 if they have a choice anyways, since their developer experience is also outdated (eg there's no support for awaiting a request within a middleware).

### 3. Local Machine

It could also just be that your computer is slow, etc. That's another reason to start by rerunning a standardized benchmark instead of creating your own.

Comment: I tried fastify and got the same response time, almost 3s.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ruiz then you know your node server is not your bottleneck, yet.

Comment: I added some more details so you can at least see some improvements locally.

Answer (score 1):

Define slow to begin with. You have `Array(5000).fill()` which we can interpreted as reserved me 5000 slots in memory for me in other word you do a for loop of 5000 then you do 5000 request  so that means 10,000 looping. Do the same 10,000 looping on java and compare then tell me if JavaScript is slow.
Also I don’t know if you have, but axios has quite a few internal validations

Comment: The 5000 array loop is almost instant. The problem lies on the await. I.e., for some reason, either when sending or receiving the requests, something is taking too long (for computer standards). If you make 5000 requests to google.com, they will reply all of them in less than 300ms, and that's with internet latency, something that doesn't exist on my example because I'm running locally.

Comment: Google has an infrastructure of a billion dollars it creates instances on demand, on the other hand you have a pc with runing a single instance, so while you have a single instance of node google creates hundreds of servers. Do not compare’em two, as one is a language an the other one is a company `google!==node` do the same exact example with other languages